# Strike view with line

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I wanna achieve an horizontal line that strikes a whole view inside a ListView, so I give the effect of striking the whole element in the listview.

How can I achieve this? I have found how to make a line below the view, but not over it.

[image: Example of a normal state view and a striked one]

Comment: But I think that is for adding a strikethrough over the text, I want to strike the whole view, let me upload a graphic example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, if someone founds this useful:

Create a FrameLayout, inside of it I put the LinearLayout (with my TextViews) inside of it, and then a View with height=1dp width=fill_parent, and gravity of center.

The FrameLayout actually was created to make multiple layer views so it was the perfect thing.

Also for the details, in the listAdapter I make the View visible or gone.

Answer (score 2):

This will create a strike out line on your view

```
  <View
          android:id="@+id/View_Strike"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_below="@id/Layout_myRow"
              android:layout_height="1dp"
              android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Now where you are designing a **row layout** for your **listview**. place this above view in such a way that it overlaps you **Text View** at the desired position in you Row Layout

and set its `visibility Gone`

Now depending on the Situation when you have to strike thru Your Item make its `Visibility Visible`

Surely is the solution !! i have used it in one of my app

Comment: This is the way. Just remember that the parent layout have to be `RelativeLayout` to use `layout_below` on child +1

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is a standard fast way of doing such a thing, but you can always create a view of `fill_parent` width and `1dp` height and strike the whole view centering it relative to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

make your custome view like stike image and make `visible` `invisible` as per your requirment over the current `view`